# react native flatlist with several arrays of data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'M new to RN and need some help
I have an object like

```
{title:"title",price:"price",subtitle:"subtitle"}
```

And I'd like to use 2 values at flatlist, like here -

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
            subtitle={item.email}
         />
        )}

      />
    </List>
```

But in this example wasn't show structure of data so I'm confused what should I do. Please help me to solve it!
At the end (render) I need a ListItem this view -

```
(title)  (price)
```

Or I should better use native-base, but the same questions about 2 value, passing to list item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass an array into the data property, then you can do:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => ( //this part will iterate over every item in the array and return a listItem
      <ListItem
        key={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        price={item.price}
     />
    )}

  />
</List>
```

Comment: ok but is it possible to pass 2 arrays? or what render method better use in my case if Flatlist or ListView doesn't work for me?

Comment: I think what you mean *2 arrays* is about *array of objects*. that's perfectly fine for something like this `[{title:"title",price:"price",subtitle:"subtitle"}, {title:"title",price:"price",subtitle:"subtitle"}]`. just push multiple of your object into single array, should works fine with `FlatList`.

Comment: If you have two different arrays that you need information from, you need to merge them into one array for flatlist/listview to work

Comment: but given array doesn't had id, so how can we use `key={item.id} ` in `<ListItem/>`?

Comment: You don't have to use id, but it has to be something that would be unique.